# How to rember $_POST var from previous <form method>?

Tags: php, forms, post, submit, refresh

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){

    echo    '<form method="post" action="">
                <select name="class_name">
                    <option value="class_id">name</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Proceed">
            </form>';
}
else{
    $_SESSION['var_name'] = $_POST['class_name'];       
    $sql = "SELECT (...) students.class_id = " . $_SESSION['var_name'];
    $que = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);        

    echo    '<table border 1>
                <tr><th>Last</th><th>Name</th><th>Add</th></tr>';

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($que)){ //<-HERE I GOT A ERROR
                    echo    '<tr><td>' . $row['user_last'] . '</td><td>' . $row['user_name'] . '</td>
                                 <td>   <form method="post" action="">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="usr_id" value = "' . $row['user_id'] . '"/>
                                            <input type="submit" name="button" value="+" />
                                        </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>';
                }
    echo    '</table>';

    if (isset($_POST['button'])){
        //DOESEN'T MATTER
    }
}
```

Ok, so my problem is that after clicking on my button from the second  i got the error mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line I've commented above. I know that after clicking the value of _SESSION var is lost. My question is how to store this thing. I've tried session management but nothing.

I forgot to add, that I'm opening a session in included file.

Comment: use a session, pass the values as hidden form fields in the next page, blah blah blah. You've got lots of options. pick one and go with it.

Comment: worst answer ever :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Sessions, and make sure you have a

```
session_start();
```

on each page.

Comment: I'm including php file with session_start() on every page.